# Send date to the server using Ksoap2

Tags: java, android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to send request to the server, and one of the argument there should to have type `date`. How to set type date? Because right now my request has type `string`.

Request which I'm sending to the server:

```
    <v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <v:Header /><v:Body><n0:getOutlets id="o0" c:root="1" xmlns:n0="http://www.kltro.com">
            <userId i:type="d:string">a24f0c23-5f36-11e4-b332-984be174a0cc</userId>
            <date i:type="d:string">2016-08-25</date>
</n0:getOutlets>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

Activity for the sending request:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.kltro.com";
    private static final String METHODNAME = "getOutlets";
    private static final String WSDL = "http://mapx.kashkan.org:5445/tro/ws/kltro";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + "#kltro:" + METHODNAME;
    private static String TAG = "soap";

    public static String callWebservice() {
        String responseDump = "";
        String requestDump="";

        try {
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHODNAME);
            request.addProperty("userId", "a24f0c23-5f36-11e4-b332-984be174a0cc");
            request.addProperty("date", "2016-08-25");

            envelope.bodyOut = request;
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL);
            transport.debug = true;
            try {
                transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                requestDump = transport.requestDump;
                responseDump = transport.responseDump;

                Log.e(TAG, requestDump +"requestDump");
                Log.e(TAG, responseDump+"responseDump");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                Log.e(TAG, requestDump +"requestDump");
                Log.e(TAG, responseDump+"responseDump");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.e(TAG, requestDump+"responseDump");
            Log.e(TAG, responseDump+"responseDump");
        }

        Log.e("requestDump", requestDump);
        Log.e(TAG, responseDump+"responseDump");
        return responseDump;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        callWebservice();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending a date through `ksoap2-android` library is a bit more complicated. `ksoap2-android` library does not know to serialize(or marshal) the type date. So you need to give a custom `Marshal` class.

But luckily `ksoap2-android` library already has a `MarshalDate` class. See its source [here](https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-base/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/serialization/MarshalDate.java).

All you need to do is register this class to your SoapSerializationEnvelope.

Check out the code below,

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.kltro.com";
private static final String METHODNAME = "getOutlets";
private static final String WSDL = "http://mapx.kashkan.org:5445/tro/ws/kltro";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + "#kltro:" + METHODNAME;
private static String TAG = "soap_tester";

public static String callWebservice() {
    String responseDump = "";
    try {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        // Register the Date Marshal class
        new MarshalDate().register(envelope);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHODNAME);
        request.addProperty("userId", "a24f0c23-5f36-11e4-b332-984be174a0cc");

        // Your date
        String dateStr = "2016-08-25";

        // Parse the date into an object of type java.util.Date
        SimpleDateFormat sdfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

        // You might want to play around with the timezones
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("ru"), Locale.ENGLISH);
        calendar.setTime(sdfIn.parse(dateStr));

        // Clear the hour, minute and second
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Date date = calendar.getTime();;

        // Create a property with the date object and type as java.util.Date.class
        PropertyInfo dateProperty = new PropertyInfo();
        dateProperty.setValue(date);
        dateProperty.setName("date");
        dateProperty.setType(Date.class);

        // Add it to the request
        request.addProperty(dateProperty);

        envelope.bodyOut = request;
        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(WSDL);
        transport.debug = true;
        try {
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            String requestDump = transport.requestDump;
            responseDump = transport.responseDump;
            Log.e(TAG, requestDump);
            Log.e(TAG, responseDump);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return responseDump;
}
```

This is the `requestDump`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<v:Envelope xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <v:Header />
   <v:Body>
      <n0:getOutlets xmlns:n0="http://www.kltro.com" id="o0" c:root="1">
         <userId i:type="d:string">a24f0c23-5f36-11e4-b332-984be174a0cc</userId>
         <date i:type="d:dateTime">2016-08-24T00:00:00.000Z</date>
      </n0:getOutlets>
   </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

Good luck :)

Comment: I am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 2018-10-03T05:40:19.000+05:30

Can you suggest me the reason for the same.